# sql update column with info from another table where linking column has duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, foreign-keys

*customer Table1*

```
ID----AccName--Customer
1-----zzz1 --------paul
2-----zzz1 --------joe
3-----aaa2--------ann
4-----zzz2--------don
```

have to update Sales table with the Customer ID, table has to look like this

*sales Table2*

```
ID----AccName----CustID-------Customer---balance
1-----zzz1---------------2----Joe--- ----------$10
2-----zzz2---------------4----Don ----------$19
3-----zzz1---------------1----Paul ----------$27

update Table2
set Table2.CustID = Table1.ID
from Table2 left join Table1 on Table2.AccName = Table1.AccName
```

*problem is it returns same CustID

*sales Table2*

```
ID----AccName----CusID---------Customer-----balance
1-----zzz1---------------1-----joe ----------$10
2-----zzz2---------------4-----don ----------$19
3-----zzz1---------------1-----paul ----------$27
```

Comment: "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Please tell us which version of SQL you are using (e.g MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: Is there any hidden logic behind your expected result that you did not reveal? Why  the row with Customer ID=1 should be set to 2 and the row with Customer ID=3 should be set to 1, since they both have AccName='zzz1'?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its SQL server

Comment: @forpas it is auto incremented

Comment: You did not answer: why the in the 1st row with AccName='zzz1' the CustID must be set to 2 and in the 3d row with AccName='zzz1' again the CustID must be set to 1?

Comment: @forpas because they have different customers

Comment: @CheriChoc *they have different customers* it's **this column** CusID that you want to update. Do you want it to be updated based on its previous value?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should also consider joining on the customer id form both tables?

```
    update Table2 
       set Table2.CustID = Table1.ID 
     from Table2 
left join Table1 
       on Table2.AccName = Table1.AccName
      and Table2.Customer= Table1.Customer
```

Comment: it gives me nulls on custID

Comment: How is it to be understood that 1 --zzz1 - with 10$ should belong to Paul and not to Joe

Comment: I've updated the table, I forgot to add Customer name to table2. Please have a look. It does appear but only shows the same custID

Comment: I have updated my code, It works by comparing Customer and Acc Name and updates the custid based on the combination from Table1

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from your syntax that you are using SQL Server.

You seem to want to enumerate the values.  Something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by accname order by id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     )
update toupdate
    set CustID = t1.ID
    from toupdate join
         (select t1.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by accname order by id) as seqnum
          from table1 t1
         ) t1
         on toupdate.accnum = t1.accnum and toupdate.seqnum = t1.seqnum;
```

Comment: is the query not missing a SET statement

Comment: IT still brings duplicate CustId, Is it not possible to do something like; where t1.customer is unique or where t2.custId does not already exist